# How from github, not to clone the large files managed by git-lfs?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

In case a github repository (for example /user/myRepository) has large data files managed by [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), when we clone the repository (with git-lfs installed on the client) with `git clone https://github.com/user/myRepository.git`, we get the whole repository (including the large files) and it can be quite long.

Is there a solution to not recover large files if you want to quickly clone only codes (without large files)?

I tried naively to do:

```
git lfs uninstall
```

before to do:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/myRepository.git
```

and it took long time and the large files was cloned ...

**I look for a simple method like:**

I want the large files, I do:

```
git lfs install
git clone https://github.com/user/myRepository.git
```

I want to be fast and I don't need large files, I do:

```
git lfs  uninstall
git clone https://github.com/user/myRepository.git
```

Comment: Why is it so hard to find this question? This is the very first thing I tried to do with LFS as, first and foremost, I want to keep my _local_ repository slim and don't primarily care about the remote repository's size.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1` while cloning and then use `git lfs pull` to pull down the large files if you want to check them out later.

The environment variable is documented in the `git-lfs-config(5)` manual page.

Comment: Since Travis CI does the clone for you, you'd need to read its documentation to see if there's an option you need to set or if it's possible to do at all.

Comment: Yes, thank you. For reference, I was stupid not to see that under the `git` section you could specify `lfs_skip_smudge`.